# What is name of temporary buffer in emacs terminology

Tags: emacs

There are some kind of buffers in Emacs, that are readonly and thay can be closed on `q` key.
For example, search functionality in projectile (C-c p s g) opens search results buffer which can be closed just pressing `q` key.

What name of this kind of buffers in Emacs terminology and how to manage them programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, read-only buffers which can be closed with <kbd>q</kbd> are likely to have the major mode `special-mode`, or some derivative thereof.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Basic Major Modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This kind of buffers in **temporary buffer**.
You can put your output to temporary buffer using `with-output-to-temp-buffer` function

A good article about this - [Emacs: Capture Shell Command Output in Temporary Buffer](http://jakemccrary.com/blog/2013/08/10/emacs-capture-shell-command-output-in-temporary-buffer/)

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear. Temporary buffers do not necessarily bind `q` to quit or anything similar. Keybindings of temporary buffers are not necessarily similar at all. Look at `*Messages*` and `*scratch*`, for example.

There is no single definition of "*temporary*" buffer in Emacs. That term just means (roughly) any buffer that a user is not likely to save or want to save. In general, any non-file buffer could be thought of as temporary.

Buffers for which `q` performs some sort of quit operation are not necessarily temporary either, but they often are (not expected to be saved). You can save any buffer using `C-x C-w` - a `*Help*` buffer, for instance. And even when `q` quits the window or buffer in some sense, the exact behavior can be quite different from one buffer to another.

Finally, user settings can affect what things like `q` (quit) operations do. And they can depend on the particular buffer as well.

In short, the question is not specific enough to draw a helpful answer. But perhaps some of the above can help a general understanding. My suggestion is to pose another, very specific question.